# Creating C# OAuth 2 client

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm creating my own OAuth 2.0 client in C#. It does work, but I'm wondering if the function which does an authorization is correct and safe. Should I do some data encryption? I've seen some OAuth clients doing HMACSHA1 encryption. Sorry but I'm new to this things. Here goes the code:

```
public string getAccessToken()
{
    string uri = "http://192.168.1.89:8080/oauth/token";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
        string.Format("{0}:{1}", client_id, client_secret))));

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters["password"] = password;
    parameters["username"] = username;
    parameters["grant_type"] = grant_type;
    parameters["scope"] = scope;
    parameters["client_id"] = client_id;
    parameters["client_secret"] = client_secret;

    var response = client.PostAsync(uri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine((response.StatusCode.ToString()));
    string resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);

    string s = "access_token\":\"";
    string token = resultContent.Substring(resultContent.IndexOf(s) + s.Length, tokenLength);
    return token;
}
```

Comment: Are you intending on supporting a specific flow or grant types? Different grant types take in different parameters (for example, client credentials and authorization flows don't take a password, but the password grant type does). Additionally, you may want to enforce https, otherwise, you risk sending over authentication information in plaintext over the internet.

Comment: It's a password flow. What about using http and encrypting the data? Will it be safe?

Comment: If you're going to encrypt your http message body, that means the server would need to know how to decrypt it. Given the OAuth2 spec doesn't call for a specific type of encryption (aside from TLS), if this is intended to be a generic client for password flow, the server would not know how to decrypt it. Are you intending this to be usable with any service that supports OAuth2 password flow, or are you writing this to interface with a specific application that you are implementing?

Comment: I'm writing my own web application.